# Java MySQL preparedStatement Batch

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file, prepared-statement

I am trying to use the preparedStatement Batch but I am having a problem.

The following code does not give me errors, but it inserts in the table only last key of the map and I do not know why.

It will be surely a very stupid error, but this is the first time I use the addBatch() method..

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        this.connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + this.database + "?user=" + this.user + "&password=" + this.password);
        String s;
        for (String key : this.map.keySet())
        {
            s = ("insert into " + this.database + ".user (nickname) values (?)");
            this.preparedStatement = this.connect.prepareStatement(s);
            this.preparedStatement.setString(1, key);
            this.preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }

        this.preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no good reason for 'connect' and 'preparedStatement' to be member variables. All that's accomplishing is introducing thread-unsafety, and scope for other errors. Make them local variables.

Comment: @EJP yes, I have taken part of code from an example.. I will correct it when I will be more confident with it. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepare your Statement and query outside of the loop:

```
      s = ("insert into " + this.database + ".user (nickname) values (?)");
      this.preparedStatement = this.connect.prepareStatement(s);
      for (String key : this.map.keySet())
        {
            this.preparedStatement.setString(1, key);
            this.preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        this.preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works! Now i would have another question about batch process, I will open another question! Take a look in few minutes please! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using the addBatch() method wrong. In your code you are doing the prepareStatement in each iteration of for loop, and this replaces the prepared query each time.

You should only be calling prepareStatement once per batch. You should place the prepared statement before the loop (only one call)